# Changing logic for /tickets API in CAS

Tags: cas

Reference: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

I would like to change the logic behind `POST /cas/v1/tickets`  How would I go about doing that?

Basically, I need the logic to make an API call to a different software. Depending on the response to that call I decide whether or not the user authenticates correctly or not.

I see that in reslet-servlet.xml there is a TicketResource object associated to /tickets.  Do I start there by inheriting it? Where do I start?  Am I looking at the write file?

```
<bean id="root" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
                <property name="attachments">
                        <map>
                                <entry key="/tickets">
                                        <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder">
                                                <lookup-method name="createResource" bean="ticketResource" />
                                        </bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a good way to start : inheriting from TicketResource and implementing your own logic in acceptRepresentation method...